# How to resolve "disk full" error on Azure ML?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am having an issue where the disk of my compute instance gets full after running some number of ML jobs on it. I have scoured the internet but been unable to find much information on how to resolve this issue. When the disk gets full, it puts my compute instance in an "unusable" state, and I am advised that I must delete some files before I can reboot the instance.

[image]

The problem is, I have no idea what files to delete. Obviously, some files are created during my ML jobs that are stored somewhere on the file drive, but I don't know what these files are or where they are stored. Furthermore, the file drive is very confusing and unintuitive:

[image]

I have deleted all the jobs that ran on the compute instance from the Azure ML Studio, thinking that this would remove any and all files that had been created during these jobs. But this was not the case - the jobs were deleted, but the compute instance is still unusable. The following links have provided some information about the issue, though not nearly enough for me to know what to do.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-compute-instance?view=azureml-api-2  (at the very bottom)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74511674/7302006  This seems relevant, though if this is the case I'm still unsure what to do about it. I have noticed that the swapfile under /mnt is 62 GB in size, which seems problematic. I do not have the permissions to delete it. [image]

https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/ypkdiu/help_to_solve_the_disk_full_error_when_running/  Though the question is related, there is no useful info about how to resolve the "disk full" issue. The compute instance remains "unusable".

If anybody has any insight into this, I would be immensely grateful and I'm sure this would come in handy for future Azure developers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not track mount really, so don't look at /mnt (I might be wrong here, but let's assume it is as truth for now)

I lost few VMs in "unusable" state because of lack of the storage on the VM disk, usually it is a docker images or virtual envs like conda with all that packages, dependencies and different versions.

So my receipt:

See what is your space usage actually on VM, not mount:

`df -h`

take a look at first row /dev/root and don't bother yourself with other rows:
[image: first screenshot, df -h results]

so in my case it is 60 gigs used, to see what exactly eating space on this VM:

`du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 10`

[image: second screenshot, du result]

okay, I don't need to worry about `/mnt` as we agreed, and on `/usr` as well as it system libs and etc. the most interesting it is `/anaconda`

to go deeper I use the same command again, but with one more level to anaconda catalogue:

`du -hsx /anaconda/* | sort -rh | head -n 10`

[image: third screenshot, more details of du command in anaconda folder]

doing the same for next folder 'envs' I see who is the main consumer:

[image]

simply destroy such env via conda with `conda remove -n` command + your can do `rm -rf` to that catalogue in the end, so get rid of it completely. If you don't need it for your experiment runs of course (as in my case).

This is not ideal set of actions, but once per year/week/day works OK.

To cleanup docker image better to check it with `docker image list` and remove unused as it is more complicated to keep track of it with df/du.

You can simply apply the same list of actions to your case and see what exactly consumes space on your compute instance in AML. Maybe even wrap as startup script or so to do clean-ups in automatic way from time to time, if that possible.

Also, there are different ways of doing your experiments, but if you have decent amount of experiments to run on your compute instance, I strongly suggest to use remote execution in AML on compute clusters and not compute instances. Those cluster nodes are disposable after each run and don't have such accumulated problems. It would be more efficient but you will have lack of debugging possibilities, so does not work great for ad-hoc experiments but still worth to try it.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! Question though: are these conda environments safe to delete? I don't think I'm using them since I specify my own custom environment for each job I run with the az ml cli, but I want to make sure. The custom environment is a typical registered environment on Azure ML studio, so it has a base docker image and a conda file specification.

Comment: I agree that running on compute clusters are typically better and have less problems. Compute instances are good for just single jobs and for debugging purposes though I find.

Comment: I think it is safe to remove default conda environments provided by azure, probably they create it for users so they have more smooth experience with AML out of the box. older compute instances has different conda envs in comparison to freshly created. So I would say if you don't use it then go ahead and remove with `conda remove --name ENV_NAME --all` and especially if you already have control over virtual envs by yourself. I thought it may affect az cli installation but not really, it can be installed into the system without conda at all.